# Is Apache redirect secure enough, and can be trusted to always keep everyone out?

Tags: security, apache-2.4, virtualhost, rewrite

On my development server, log in is with a certificate only (HTTPS on 443), While HTTP on 80 is redirecting to HTTPS.
Without the redirect the ACCESS IS NOT RESTRICTED and everyone can go everywhere, because i can't do "require" on the HTTP and not HTTPS because "require" works only on LOCATION/FILE not on VHOST.

**Can redirect be trusted to always deny access to HTTP? Is it secure enough?**

Relevant settings:

At location /var/www/html/:

```
Require All granted
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

At vhost [server ip]:80

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

At vhost [server ip]:433

```
SSLVerifyClient require
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If every request gets redirected, there's nothing else left. However, you are over-complicating things with your `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`. The HTTP `VirtualHost` could only have a single simple [mod_alias `Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) for everything. When it doesn't even have any `DocumentRoot` it also becomes easier to realize it won't serve any content.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```